# Add a combo box in a specific row in datagrid view c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to have a combobox in a specific cell in my data grid view. can somebody help? For the table I'm using data table

Problem: I want to put a combobox in a specific cell like in column 1 and row 1.

Here is how I populate the table--

```
public DataTable createGridForForm(int rows, int columns)
{              
    // Create the output table.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        // populate data row with values here
        ListBox test = new ListBox();
        myTabPage.Controls.Add(test);
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return table;
}
```

And here is how I create the datagridview.

```
private void createGridInForm(int rows, int columns)
{
    DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);

    //DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
    //ID_Column.Width = 200;

    int positionForTable = getLocationForTable();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Size = new Size(995, 200);
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Location = new Point(5, positionForTable);
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);                   
}
```

here is my whole code----

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String line;
        String typeOfTable;
        int amountOfTablesInTab;


        delegate void SetComboBoxCellType(int iRowIndex);

        bool bIsComboBox = false;

        List<TabPage> tapPages = new List<TabPage>();

        TabPage myTabPage;
        DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView; 


        private const String TABS = "TABS";
        private const String TABLES = "TABLES";
        private const String GRID = "grid";
        private const String LIST = "list";

        private const int LOCATION_TABLE_TYPE = 2;
        private const int LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_ROWS = 3;
        private const int LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_COLUMNS = 4;
        private const int AMOUNT_COLUMNS_IN_LIST = 2;
        private const int LOCATION_TAB_FOR_TABLE = 1;
        private const int STARTING_POSITION_FOR_TABLES = 5;
        private const int TABLE_SIZE= 205;

        String[] splitTableArray;
        List<String> tabList = new List<String>();
        List<String> tablesList = new List<String>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //test();
           getFormContentFromFile();   
        }

        private void getFormContentFromFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("neo2G.res"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line.Equals(TABS))
                    {

                        while (!line.Equals(".."))
                        {
                            line = reader.ReadLine();


                            if (!line.Equals("..") && !line.Equals(""))
                            {
                                tabList.Add(line);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (line.Equals(TABLES))
                    {
                        while (!line.Equals(".."))
                        {
                            line = reader.ReadLine();

                            if (!line.Equals(".."))
                            {

                                tablesList.Add(line);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                createTablesInTab();

            }
        }

        private void searchTablesToMatch(int tabCount)
        {
                 int tableCount = 0;
            int tabLocationForTables;
            amountOfTablesInTab = 0;


            foreach(String table in tablesList)
            {
                splitTableLineToArray(tablesList[tableCount]);

                if (int.TryParse(splitTableArray[LOCATION_TAB_FOR_TABLE], out tabLocationForTables))
                {

                    if(tabLocationForTables == tabCount)
                    {
                        typeOfTable = splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_TYPE];
                        amountOfTablesInTab++;


                        if(typeOfTable.Equals(LIST))
                        {

                            createListInForm(int.Parse(splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_ROWS]));

                        }

                        else if(typeOfTable.Equals(GRID))
                        {


                            createGridInForm(int.Parse(splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_ROWS]), int.Parse(splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_COLUMNS]));
                        }
                    }
                {

                }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The format for TABLES must be identical to the table format in the Configuration file format", "File Error", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                tableCount++;
            }
        }

        private int getLocationForTable()
         {
             int position = 0;

             for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfTablesInTab; i++)
             {
                 position = position + TABLE_SIZE;

                 if (i == 1)
                 {
                     position = STARTING_POSITION_FOR_TABLES;
                 }
             } 
           return position;
        }


        private void createGridInForm(int rows, int columns)
        {

            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);


            c.Items.Add("A");
            c.Items.Add("B");
            c.Items.Add("C");


            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);
            //Assign it to your dataGridView
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[1] = c;


            int positionForTable = getLocationForTable();
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Size = new Size(995, 200);
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Location = new Point(5, positionForTable);





        }

        private void createListInForm(int rows)
        {
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createListForForm(rows);
            int positionForTable = getLocationForTable();
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;


            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Size = new Size(995, 200);
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Location = new Point(5, positionForTable);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);
        }
        private void createTablesInTab()
        {
             int countTab = 0;

            foreach (String tab in tabList)
            {

                countTab++;
                createTabInForm(tab);
                searchTablesToMatch(countTab);
               }
}

        private void createTabInForm(String tabName)
        {
            tabName = Regex.Replace(tabName, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
            tabName = tabName.Trim(':', '"');
            myTabPage = new TabPage(tabName);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

            myTabPage.AutoScroll = true;

        }

        private void splitTableLineToArray(String tableLine)
        {
            splitTableArray = tableLine.Split(',');
        }

        public DataTable createGridForForm(int rows, int columns)
        {

            // Create the output table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();


                   for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());
            }


            for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
            {

                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                // populate data row with values here

                table.Rows.Add(dr);


            }

            return table;
        }


        public DataTable createListForForm(int rows)
        {

            // Create the output table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();


            for (int i = 1; i <= AMOUNT_COLUMNS_IN_LIST ; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());

            }
            for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

                // populate data row with values here

                table.Rows.Add(dr);


               }

            return table;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the 'combo box' first by using **DataGridViewComboBoxCell** class

this class has quite similar properties to the original comboBox

Try this

```
//Create comboBox
DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
c.Items.Add("A");
c.Items.Add("B");
c.Items.Add("C");

//Assign it to your dataGridView
yourDataGridView.Rows[rowNum].Cells[colNum] = c;
```

Comment: i dont know why, but the combobox doesn't  show in my data grid view :(. i dont understand what can be the problem

Comment: @mynameiswhat can you post your latest or reworked code to let me know what you have done this far..

Comment: @mynameiswhat I don't understand, the answer you just posted has completely the same meaning as mine, meaning the real errors are located within your DataTable that you assign into your DataGridView, not in the dgvComboBox part. Anyway, nice that I can help you finding your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add RowDatabound event listener to your gridview and in the event you can control the logic you want to implement on.

You can add event listener like below

```
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView_RowDataBound);
```

the event handler will be
protected void RunTimeCreatedDataGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
// logic to display check box
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
 //create columns as textbox columns(or whatever you want)
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            //add the colums to the table
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgc);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgc1);
            //set header text here if you wish

            //create dgv combobox cells and add items to the collection
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cbc.Items.Add("item 1");
            cbc.Items.Add("item 2");
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cbc1.Items.Add("item 1");
            cbc1.Items.Add("item 2");

            //create 2 rows here so that you can insert future columns without having them go above your comboboxes
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);

            //set row one cells to combobox cells
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = cbc;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1] = cbc1;
```